# ImageMagick fails to open a JPG

Tags: php, symfony, imagemagick, imagick

I have used the avalance imagine bundle(https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine) in my symfony2 web app to resize and create thumbnails. My server is centOS.
When my form uploads the image and imagine tries to open with "`**lcms: Error #12288; Pointer error;** probably corrupted file`" in the apache error log. I tried catching the exception while opening but the catch block is never executed. I dont know what is the problem.

```
try{
$this->imagine->open($path);
}catch(\Exception $e){
die($e->getMessage());
}
```

And the image is http://rghost.net/56833261

My server is centos machine and this is happening only with CMYK colorspaced images.
I get this error while processing cmyk images

> Unable to add profile sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_black_scaled.icc to image
>   [465]

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the image file that you're trying to open? If possibly to a binary hosting place rather than imgur.

Comment: @Danack Updated the question with the image link.

Comment: Well, it works for me (TM) when directly using Imagick or GD. Either the upload is failing, there is a bug in Imagine or something else weird is happening, but currently you probably haven't provided enough info to allow people to help you. btw if you're generating that image, PNG would be a much better format to use. It's lossless as well as smaller for that image.

Comment: @Danack I have tried this on Ubuntu 14.04 and it works correctly. My server is a CentOS machine. There its not working.

Comment: Centos often has very out of date packages. I'd recommend compiling ImageMagick from source for it.

Comment: @Danack It only happens with CYMK images. I updated the Question with error message.

Comment: was this ever solved?